# Test does run on the selenium grid in local works correctly)

Tags: java, selenium, grid

I am trying to run the code below in selenium GRID (executing the "local" code, works correctly), follows code snippet:

```
SuiteTest.xml:
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="SuiteTest" verbose="1" thread-count="2" parallel="tests"> 
        <test name="FIREFOX Test">
        <parameter name="browser" value="FIREFOX" />
        <classes>
            <class name="test.CN01_CT01_IncluirConteudoMP3" />
            <class name="test.CN01_CT02_IncluirConteudoMP4" />
        </classes>
    </test>

        <test name="CHROME Test">
        <parameter name="browser" value="CHROME" />
        <classes>
            <class name="test.CN01_CT01_IncluirConteudoMP3" />
            <class name="test.CN01_CT02_IncluirConteudoMP4" />
        </classes>
    </test>         
</suite>
```

BaseTest:

```java
public class BaseTest {

    protected static ExtentReports extent;
    public static String testName;

    @Parameters({ "browser" })
    @BeforeMethod
    public void BeforeTest(Method method, Browsers browser) throws IOException, BiffException {

        Propriedades.browser = browser;
        String browserStr = browser.toString();         
        System.out.println("Before ........" + method.getName());       
        //Recuperar nome do Teste
        testName = method.getName() + "-" + browserStr;     
        // Realizando Login
        LoginPage.realizarLogin();    
        //Iniciar o relatorio
        extent = ExtentReport.StartReport(testName);

    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void finaliza(ITestResult result) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("After ........");

        //Validar Resultado dos Testes
        ExtentReport.ResultTest(result, testName);

        // Realizar Logout
        LoginPage.realizarLogout();

        // Fechando Browser
        if (Propriedades.FECHAR_BROWSER) {
            killDriver();
        }
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public static void finalizaTudo(){
        DriverFactory.killDriver();
        extent.flush();
        System.out.println("AfterSuite........");
        System.out.println(ExtentReport.diretorioReport);
        //DriverFactory.executeChrome(ExtentReport.diretorioReport);
    }

}
```

BasePage:

```java
public class BasePage {

    protected static DSL dsl;

    static List<String> result = Ambiente.dadosAmbiente();
    static String url = result.get(0);
    protected static String user = result.get(1);
    protected static String pass = result.get(2);

    public BasePage() {
        dsl = new DSL();
    }

}
```

DSL:

```java
public class DSL {

    public void clicarRadio(By by) {
        getDriver().findElement(by).click();
    }   

Other methods to access the screen elements (Text, Click, Button, Radio, Combo and etc.)

(...)

}
```

DriveFactory:

```java
public class DriverFactory {

    static WebDriver driver;

    private DriverFactory() {
    }

    public static WebDriver getDriver() {           

        if(Propriedades.tipoExecucao == TipoExecucao.LOCAL){

                if (driver == null) {
                    switch (Propriedades.browser) {
                    case CHROME:
                        executeChrome(BasePage.url);
                        break;
                    case FIREFOX:
                        executeFirefox(BasePage.url);
                        break;
                    case IE:
                        executeIE(BasePage.url);
                        break;
                    case EDGE:
                        executeEgde(BasePage.url);
                        break;
                    }
                    driver.manage().window().maximize();
                }
        }

        if(Propriedades.tipoExecucao == TipoExecucao.GRID) {

            DesiredCapabilities cap = null;
                switch (Propriedades.browser) {
                case CHROME:
                    cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
                    break;
                case FIREFOX:
                    cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
                    break;
                case IE:
                    cap = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
                    break;
                case EDGE:
                    cap = DesiredCapabilities.edge();
                    break;
                }

                try {
                    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.0.72:4444/wd/hub"), cap);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    System.err.println("Falha ao conectar ao GRID");
                }
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                driver.get(BasePage.url);
                System.out.println("Abriu Browser Grid");
    }

        return driver;
}

    public static void killDriver() {
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.close();
            driver.quit();          
            driver = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Test - Class:

Test classes, just to check that execution is logging in and logout.

```java
@Test
public void CN01_CT02_IncluirConteudoMp4(){

assertEquals("123", "123");
}

@Test

public void CN01_CT01_IncluirConteudoMp3() throws InterruptedException, AWTException{

assertEquals("123", "123456");
}
```

Configuration Grid

Config (Json) - Hub:

```
{
  "port": 4444,
  "newSessionWaitTimeout": -1,
  "servlets" : [],
  "withoutServlets": [],
  "custom": {},
  "capabilityMatcher": "org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher",
  "registry": "org.openqa.grid.internal.DefaultGridRegistry",
  "throwOnCapabilityNotPresent": true,
  "cleanUpCycle": 5000,
  "role": "hub",
  "debug": false,
  "browserTimeout": 0,
  "timeout": 1800
}
```

NodeChrome:

```
{
    "capabilities": [
        {
            "browserName": "chrome",
            "maxInstances": 1,
            "webdriver.chrome.driver": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
        }
    ],
    "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
    "maxSession": 1,
    "port": 5555,
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": 5000,
    "hub": "http://192.168.0.72:4444",
    "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
    "nodePolling": 5000,
    "role": "node",
    "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 60000,
    "downPollingLimit": 1,
    "debug": false,
    "servlets": [
    ],
    "withoutServlets": [

    ],
    "custom": {
    }
}
```

NodeFirefox:

```
{
    "capabilities": [
        {
            "browserName": "firefox",
            "maxInstances": 1,
            "webdriver.gecko.driver": "C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe"
        }
    ],
    "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
    "maxSession": 1,
    "port": 5556,
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": 5000,
    "hub": "http://192.168.0.72:4444",
    "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
    "nodePolling": 5000,
    "role": "node",
    "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 60000,
    "downPollingLimit": 1,
    "debug": false,
    "servlets": [

    ],
    "withoutServlets": [

    ],
    "custom": {
    }
}
```

When executing the code using Selenium GRID, the system opens two browsers but does not log in, problem occurs (apparently sync problem).

Example:

The login field is filled in "twice" and "Invalid Login" is returned.

Code is executed using the Eclipse IDE.
Run (SuiteTest.xml) - Run with TestNG

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in your test code. Your `DriverFactory` is initialising a static data member in `driver`. Now when you run your tests in parallel via your suite xml file, your tests are really competing with each other and end up overwriting the static data member. You need to refactor your test code. There's no problem with either the Selenium Grid or TestNG for that matter here.

Comment: But as it should be my code "DriverFactory", this is my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your browser initialization and termination inside the test - like local browser variable. no global variables.

In a parallel running, we need to consider following things

1. Every test should be **unique** not dependent Test should not take
2. exceed more than 10 mins Grid machine - CPU utilization should not
   exceed 70%.
3. If your machine capable of handling 5 instances and 3
   concurrent sessions, go for 4 instances.